# Crafting a greatsword Help

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I am trying to craft a greatsword.

So far, have been following the guide written here and the following will sum it up:
Basic crafting strategy can be summed up as follows:
1. Create a gem with stats you want.
2. Create a basic item with gem created in 1.
3. Salvage the created item to get component with stats of the gem.
4. Repeat 1-3 for each of the different components used to make the item.
5. Craft the desired gear with components created in step4.

It is also stated in the guide that the part of the basic item with the gem effect always appeared on the 2nd component of the item i will salvage in step 3.

In my greatsword, I now have the 2nd component (Hilt) with the gem effect.
I got that in 1 try when I salvaged a greatsword.

I am now trying to get the 3rd component (Grip) with gem effect.
I created a Gauntlets with gem, but when I try to salvage it, I am not getting the upgraded Grip. I believe the gem that I used is the pristine one and the effect is 20% damage at day.

My Blacksmithing is level 8 and Sagecrafting is level 8 as well.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Since I am crafting a greatsword, I already got my Hilt with fire something effect.

What I want next is to get a Grip with +20% damage during day effect.

So what I did is create a Gaunlet with +20% damage during day gem. (because the second component needed for gaunlet is Grip, and it states in the guide that almost always, the effect of the gem is transfered to the 2nd component).

The problem is, I whenever I salvage the gaunlet, I always get a normal Grip with only +5 health effect in it.

How do I get the Grip with +20% damage during day effect?

Thanks

Comment: I just skipped all that and instead as ruler of the island (DLC) I would send trade delegations for crafting supplies. You can get good parts a level early that way.